# MySQL workbench: Cannot Connect to Database Server (ssh)

Tags: mysql, linux, permissions, mysql-workbench, remote

General pointers would be appreciated -- it's likely I'm misunderstanding the mechanisms involved in a remote connection through ssh.  I **can** use ssh to connect remotely, and **then**, through the CLI, connect to MySQL.  I'd like to do that with MySQL Workbench.

I don't understand the parameters to send:

[image: ssh_workbench]

From the CLI, `ssh thufir@192.168.1.2` works **without** a password because the key authenticates.  Once I'm logged in, I can then access the database as so:

```
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ ssh thufir@192.168.1.2
Last login: Mon Feb 23 06:52:53 2015 from 192.168.1.3
Thank you for installing ViciBox Server v.6.0!
This software is available for free download at
http://www.vicibox.com. If you paid for this 
software you have been ripped off. Please report
any fraud or abuses of this software to 
abuse@vicidial.com. Please report any bugs on 
the forum at http://www.vicidial.org

To configure the LAN settings type:
yast lan

To change the server IP in the database type:
/usr/share/astguiclient/ADMIN_update_server_ip.pl

Official paid-for ViciDial support is available at 
http://www.vicidial.com

Free community-based ViciDial Support is available
at http://www.vicidial.org/VICIDIALforum

- ViciBox Redux v.6.0.3-141118
thufir@tleilax:~> 
thufir@tleilax:~> mysql -u root asterisk
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 1349
Server version: 5.5.33-MariaDB-log openSUSE package

Copyright (c) 2000, 2013, Oracle, Monty Program Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [asterisk]> 
MariaDB [asterisk]>
```

([ViciDial redux](http://www.vicibox.com/) ships without password the the MySQL root user; for the time being I'll leave that as is.)

I've tried a few different users; I've enabled and disabled "use old authentication protocol" without result.

To go through the specifics:

```
MySQL WB Setup

For Connection Method, select Standard TCP/IP over SSH

Set the name to whatever you want, preferably an easily recognizable label.

Under the Parameters Tab, enter the following information:

SSH Hostname: Your server IP address or URL
SSH Username: mysql-tunnel
SSH Password: leave blank/click “Clear” to be safe
SSH Keyfile: ~/.ssh/id_rsa (or if using Windows the keyfile generated by PuTTy)
MySQL Hostname: 127.0.0.1
MySQL Port: 3306
Username: (We will provide this – your database username)
Password: (We will provide this – your database password)

Click the Advanced tab and make sure Use the old authentication protocol is checked.
```

http://www.sononaco.com/faqs/connecting-to-databases-using-mysql-workbench/

*old* authentication method?  Sounds suspect..

hostname:      192.168.1.2

ssh username:  the name I login with over ssh, "thufir" as in "thufir@192.168.1.2"

ssh password:  there's no password during ssh, it uses a key...

ssh key file:  well, I just typed in the path manually

the other connection parameters are those MySQL connection paramters which I use **once** I'm logged in through ssh?

The full error from Workbench is:

```
Cannot Connect to Database Server

Your connection attempt failed for user 'root' from your host to server at tleilax:3306:
  Tunnel error: Remote connection to tleilax:3306 failed: AttributeError("'Transport' object has no attribute 'window_size'",)

Please:
1 Check that mysql is running on server tleilax
2 Check that mysql is running on port 3306 (note: 3306 is the default, but this can be changed)
3 Check the root has rights to connect to tleilax from your address (mysql rights define what clients can connect to the server and from which machines) 
4 Make sure you are both providing a password if needed and using the correct password for tleilax connecting from the host address you're connecting from
```

Starting with #3, I don't *want* (MySQL) root to connect from **any** address except localhost...isn't the point of using ssh that I first login as a user, and then workbench, only after logging in to the system, **then** initiates a database connection?

Troubleshooting steps:

```
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ telnet 192.168.1.2 3306
Trying 192.168.1.2...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out
thufir@doge:~$
```

so...port 3306 is closed.  But that's ok, because ssh uses port 22..

and:

```
thufir@tleilax:~> 
thufir@tleilax:~> mysql -u root -h 127.0.0.1 
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 1529
Server version: 5.5.33-MariaDB-log openSUSE package

Copyright (c) 2000, 2013, Oracle, Monty Program Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [(none)]>
```

can connect once connected via ssh...

Finally:

```
ssh -L 33000:192.168.1.2:3306 thufir@192.168.1.2
```

connects me fine to tleilax..admittedly, I'm not quite sure what those parameters mean, I'll have to look them up.

See also this excellent question:

[Can't connect to MySQL database over SSH with Workbench](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12154/cant-connect-to-mysql-database-over-ssh-with-workbench?rq=1)

Comment: Make sure mysql is actually listening on port 3306 - I think you're just connecting via a fd at the moment - verify with `netstat -an | grep 3306 | grep LISTEN`

Answer (score 1):

No you can't.

SSH is an operating system for remote administration, what is happening when you do ssh and directly enter to the database is because of a script or default shell changed in /etc/passwd for the specific user.

But for mariadb(mysql) (including workbench) this means nothing, cause in practice is very likely to do ssh root@yourserver and then mysql -pyourpass.

So ssh is not the protocol you are looking for.